# MYSQL - Insert into table if not exists with no obvious primary/unique key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 2 columns, they are 'user' and 'action' and are used to denote when a user has completed a certain action. An entry should only be made if a user has not made the given action before so I feel something like the following is what is required:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from actiontable WHERE user=1 and action=5) THEN 
INSERT INTO actiontable VALUES(1,5);
```

Yet this seems to be incorrect syntax and I can't find how I should go about this. Is this possible? Or is there some way to use a primary key or unique key to achieve this?

Comment: This is back to front.

Comment: Is there any error when you are trying to execute this.

Comment: There is, I tried search for the code and the text separately  but to no avail:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM actiontable WHERE user=1 AND action=5 at line 1

Comment: @Sam . . . You can only use `if` in the context of a stored procedure, function, or trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a primary key on user,action and then try

```
INSERT INTO actiontable (`user`,`action`) VALUES (1,5);
```

It will fail if the entry already exists. If you do not want to raise an error, you could try

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO actiontable (`user`,`action`) VALUES (1,5);
```